# How to use the Runge-Kutta 4th order method to integrate the acceleration?

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose we have the following
[dynamic equation for acceleration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8EOo.png)

We can then apply any of several known numerical integration techniques to
integrate the acceleration to compute future positions and velocities.
Given initial conditions on the motion, usually in the form [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjUIx.png)
, we integrate the dynamic equation for acceleration forward in time numerically by steps of size dt using Euler integration: Starting with t = 0, iteratively to compute [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYE8r.png)
, where, for each iteration, the dynamic equation for acceleration is computed to calculate the angular acceleration. How can we perform the Runge-Kutta 4th order method instead of Euler integration for this case?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand ? RK4 is straightforward.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but how to apply the RK4 for this particular case?  I can surly use the RK4 to solve any other ordinary differential equation, but in fact, this case can is a little complicated, and I could not apply the RK4 for.

Comment: If you can apply Euler, why can't you apply RK ?

Comment: See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/solving-coupled-odes-using-runge-kutta-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405185/is-there-a-better-way-to-tidy-this-chuck-of-code-it-is-the-runge-kutta-4th-orde

Answer (score 1):

If you used Euler's method, you realized that your equations can be written on the form
$$
\begin{cases}u_1' = u_2 \\ u_2' = f(t,u_1,u_2)\end{cases}
$$

Denoting $U=(u_1,u_2)$ and $F(t,U) = (u_2, f(t,u_1,u_2)$, RK4 would be something like

\begin{align*}
k_{1} = & F(t_n,U_n)\\
k_{2} = & F(t_n+\frac h2, U_n + \frac h2 k_{1})\\
k_{3} = & F(t_n+\frac h2, U_n + \frac h2 k_{2})\\
k_{4} = & F(t_n+h, U_n + h k_{3})\\
U_{n+1} = & U_n + \frac h6 (k_{1}+2k_{2} + 2k_{3} + k_{4})
\end{align*}